# Dependencies path difference in Gradle vs in Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar

I have a question regarding to the difference between Gradle depedencies mechanism vs Maven dependency mechanism:

My project structure is following and **app** is dependent on **common**:

```
project
    common 
         conf
         src
            java
            test
    app 
         conf
         src
            java 
            test
```

and build.gradle in **app** is:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    ....
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'conf'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test'
        }
    }
}
```

When I use *ant dist*. The class paths contain /common/conf folder, which contains lots of configuration files.
When I use Gradle build. The class paths contain build/common.jar instead of /common/conf.

Is there a way I could make Gradle do the same thing as Maven does (make class paths contain /common/conf instead of build/common.jar)?

Because **app** will read xml configuration files under common/conf folder when I run test cases under app but **app** is not able to read xml from a jar file. Because right now my code is not able to handle the inputStream from Jar.

Is it using:

```
res.getFile()
```

where res is the reference to xml configuration files.

I am a newbie to both Maven and Gradle. Could someone please help? Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to achieve is have those xml files available at runtime from within the Jar, then just add your XML files to `/src/main/resources`.

Anything in that directory automatically gets added to the Jar file and available as classpath resources. Both Maven and Gradle use convention over configuration, where it's a convention to put classpath resources into `/src/main/resources` as it is to put application Java code in `/src/main/java` and unit test classpath resources in `/src/test/resources` and unit test Java code in `/src/test/java`.

Following Mavan/Gradle conventions will make your configuration simpler too. Unlike Ant where *everything* needed to be configured.

If your xml files are in `common.jar` (by putting the xml in `common/src/main/resources`, and common is on the class path for for `app` then you should be able to read those files by getting via class loader. E.g `SomeClassFromCommon.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("somefile.xml")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This helps me to understand the underlying much better !